# Is there any way to make background image dark in Android

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I want to darken the background of a Textview and when I lower the alpha of the background it kinda becomes white. Can anyone help?
Here is my code

```
   <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bg_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/abg32"
                android:alpha="0.6"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried using the tint attribute but it doesn't work.

Comment: use background attribute on the textview xml element to put a color or in code, use setBackground method.

Comment: Could you provide your renderings?

Comment: Here is what it looks like https://imgur.com/a/R5IMBdH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Approach:**

I can see that you have mentioned the tint attribute didnt work, could you provide the code you wrote? It could be some error in it. Either way you could perhaps try this and see if it works.

```
<ImageView
    ...
    app:tint="#6F000000"/>
```

**Second Approach:**

Add a view on-top of you ImageView and set the background as color and opacity  desired

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background=“#6F000000" />
```

*Make the width and height as same as your ImageView's height and width

Comment: As i mentioned earlier tint attribute doesn't work . but second approach worked like a charm